# Are comments moved to chat in a group?

Tags: support

For [Dealing with reactions from colleague about being self-taught](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/110787/dealing-with-reactions-from-colleague-about-being-self-taught) the comments were moved to chat, and while the majority of them should have headed that way direction, and I agree with the mod that the question makes an interesting topic, the first 3 comments appear to have been clarifications on the question itself:

> How do you react now when she acts like that? What have you tried?
>   What specific outcome are you trying to achieve?
>   - [dwizum](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/342554/dwizum)
>
> Is the coworker a recent graduate? How long has this been going on?
>   ...
>   - [whrrgarbl](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/161228/whrrgarbl)
>
> Question: Have you watched her not explain "json" to others? Or does
>   she approach all people as if they don't know basic "technology"? - [WernerCD](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/27079/wernercd)

Are comments here not for clarification of the question, or is the move simply all or none?

Comment: Have in mind that this was also a HNQ, where mountains of comments can stack. In general, comments in those cases tend to become tangential to the issue/question. Chat is better place for such comments.

Comment: I'm not sure a support question about how the software works should be marked as a dupe of a discussion question about policy.

Comment: @Monica However, enderland's answer there explains the issue adequately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "move to chat" function moves everything.  Moderators can then selectively undelete comments if not *everything* should move.  I've just undeleted the three comments you identified, which look like requests for clarification.  I'm not surprised that they were missed among 43 comments and **54 flags**.  Unfortunately, sometimes things get missed under high volume, so thanks for bringing your question to meta.  (And especially thanks for not *using more comments to ask about the missing comments*. :-) )

Comment: I understand that things slip through, and it make sense to Move All instead of X+10 individual, was curious and figured that a more general question to clarify my assumption might be useful.